# Can I remap mouse co-ordinates when using Gdiplus::SetPageScale using a GDI Function?

Tags: visual-c++, gdi+, scaling

I want to add zoom capability to an app, which at its core is a spf graph app. Now I currently have no zoom, but the ability to select/move, multi-select objects on the graph in the graph window. I started to write my own code to do scaling of the objects and then work out mouse co-ordinates to map clicks and redraws correctly. I didnt complete this as I found the Gdiplus::SetPageScale function, which scales the window fine but I cannot see any GDI function I can use to map the mouse click co-ordinates from the world co-ord's to the page co-ords. I tried TransformPoints(Gdiplus::CoordinateSpaceWorld, ::Gdiplus::CoordinateSpacePage, points, 2) but this does not convert the points and the returned points are (0,0).

So is this even possible with Gdiplus or do I need to write this mapping myself? Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use Graphics::SetPageScale() in this case.  The much more general way is to use the Matrix class instead.  Its Scale, Translate and Rotate methods are handy to get the matrix you need.  You'll want to use the Scale() method here, possibly Translate() to change the origin.

Before you start drawing, activate the matrix with the Graphics::SetTransform() method.  Anything you draw will now automatically be scaled according to the arguments you passed to the Matrix::Scale() method.  Mapping a mouse position is now exceedingly simple with Matrix::TransformPoints() method, the exact same transform that was used while drawing is now applied to the mouse coordinates.  Even going back from graph coordinates to mouse coordinates is simple, use the Matrix::Invert() method to obtain the inverse transform.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now! I hadn't understood GDI+ well enough! I have replaced the existing code and used the transforms with matrices and it is exactly what I was aiming for and easy as you say. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When GDI+ draws, it applies a world transform (which is controlled by Graphics::SetTransform, ScaleTransform, etc.) followed by the page transform (which is controlled by Graphics::SetPageScale and Graphics::SetPageUnit) to transform the points to device coordinates.

So it normally goes like this: World coordinates --[World transform]--> Page coordinates --[Page transform]--> Device coordinates

You can use Graphics::TransformPoints the way you wanted, to map mouse coordinates to world coordinates, but you have to specify Device coordinates as the source space and World coordinates as the destination space.

However, there are good reasons to do it as Hans describes with a Matrix you store separately, most notably that you shouldn't be holding on to your Graphics object for long enough to process mouse input (nor should there be a need to create one then).